# High CPU usage when using ErrorProvider in WinForms, why?

Tags: winforms, performance, errorprovider

I've got an application that goes into high CPU usage (slowly over time) when the ErrorProvider control sets the blinking icon continuously on several controls.

The high CPU usage is not immediate but have a slow ramp until the application hits 100% CPU.

When there is no error shown then CPU goes back to normal. Is it normal that the ErrorProvider takes so much CPU time?

Comment: As Hans suggests, a memory leak seems most likely. Are you creating a *new* `ErrorProvider` control each time, or reusing an existing one?

Comment: @Cody I reuse the same one. Seems to be related to the blinking always on...

Comment: I suppose that explains why I've never seen it. The first thing I do is turn off that annoying blinking. I'm not sure why it needs to be the default value; the error indicator is plenty easy to see if it stands still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this MS connect bug report: [Graphical Resources Leak In ErrorProvider](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/264527/graphical-resources-leak-in-errorprovider)

> When there is an error associated with a control, the ErrorProvider component displays a blinking icon on its right. I've discovered that every time the icon blinks, an new DeviceContext is added to the System.Drawing.Internal.DeviceContexts internal list. And when I call the Dispose() method on the ErrorProvider object, the DeviceContexts list is not cleared.
>
> Consequence : by default, the icon blinks every 250 ms so 4 DeviceContext objects are added to the System.Drawing.Internal.DeviceContexts list per second. When an ErrorProvider is active and the BlinkStyle is AlwaysBlink, the list grows indefinitely ... and when this list is very big (I've seen it with 500000+ objects!) the application drawing operations are very very very slow :(

This bug is marked as fixed but the most recent comment says it is under investigation.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't normal.  In all likelihood you are leaking memory or window handles.  Start diagnosing this with Taskmgr.exe, Processes tab.  View + Select Columns and tick Memory (Commit size), Handles, USER objects and GDI objects.  Observe the values of these columns while your app runs.

Steadily increasing values indicates a problem in your code that can drive up the cpu usage.  A pretty classic problem is leaking USER handles, induced by removing controls from your form with Controls.Remove() or Controls.Clear() and forgetting to dispose those controls.

Comment: Well, it's odd, memory, handles, and the like are not increasing!

Comment: The only other scenario I can think of is getting an event subscription wrong, registering the same handler over and over again.  One event can then generate a storm of calls to the same method.  You'll ultimately need to debug this to find out where all the cycles go.  Tools + Attach to Process to attach the debugger.  A profiler is going to be handy too.

Comment: Seems the problem is not in my code after all because if I set the control to have no blinking then there's no problem. Only if I set the continuous blinking. Looks like a bug in MS code !

Comment: I can get no repro for this at all, even when blinking at a ridiculous rate with a custom icon.  I can't help you without a repro.  Not blinking sounds like a decent workaround.